# applying a very special citation style

Tags: biblatex, biber

[Edit: change requirements and change bibstyle]

The required citation style (required by someone you cannot discuss with) is as follows

[image]

I was able to get to set up a XeLaTeX example and get rid of doi, URL and isbn and find an approximate style, but now I am stuck with getting rid of the delimiters around the year, pushing the year to the end **and** get rid of the publishing house. Also the indentation might be a problem:

[image]

Any help or pointer appreciated.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{some.bib}
    @article{Salah.2010,
    abstract = {Der Beitrag identifiziert verschiedene Diskurse innerhalb des islamischen Feminismus. Es wird gefragt, ob islamischer Feminismus dazu beitr{\"a}gt, Frauenrechte zu st{\"a}rken, und inwieweit er Frauen einen Zugang zur {\"o}ffentlichen Sph{\"a}re und Autonomie in der privaten Sph{\"a}re erm{\"o}glicht. Es wird gezeigt, dass der islamische Feminismus einen positiven Einfluss auf die F{\"o}rderung von Frauenrechten hat, und zwar nicht nur innerhalb islamischer Diskurse, sondern auch in nationalen und internationalen Institutionen. Dennoch tr{\"a}gt der islamisch-feministische Diskurs auch eine m{\"o}gliche Gefahr f{\"u}r den Status von Frauen in muslimischen Gesellschaften in sich, da religi{\"o}s motivierte Argumente gegen die UN-Konvention f{\"u}r Frauenrechte vorgebracht werden, sobald diese zum islamischen Recht der Scharia im Widerspruch steht.{\textquotedbl} (Autorenreferat){\textquotedbl}This article identifies different discourses within Islamic Feminism. The question is whether it contributes to the improvement of women's rights, and in how far it enables women to attain access to public space and autonomy in the private sphere. It will be argued that Islamic Feminism has a positive influence on the promotion of women's rights, not only within Islamic discourses and movements, but also in national and international institutions. However, the Islamic-feminist discourse also carries a potential danger for the status of women in Muslim societies, since religious arguments are being directed against the UN Convention for Women's Rights insofar as it contradicts the Islamic Sharia.{\textquotedbl} (author's abstract)},
    author   = {Salah, Hoda},
    year     = {2010},
    title    = {Diskurse des islamischen Feminismus},
    keywords = {affirmative action;Africa;Afrika;{\"A}gypten;Arab countries;arabische L{\"a}nder;argumentation;conservatism;developing country;discourse;Diskurs;Egypt;Entwicklungsland;feminism;Feminismus;Frau;Gender Mainstreaming;gender relations;Geschlechterverh{\"a}ltnis;Gleichstellung;human rights;Islam;Islamic society;islamische Gesellschaft;Konservatismus;Koran;law;liberalism;Liberalismus;Macht;Menschenrechte;Middle East;Nahost;Nordafrika;North Africa;power;radicalism;Radikalismus;Recht;Religion;Scharia;Selbstbestimmung;self-determination;sharia;social status;sozialer Status;woman},
    pages    = {47--64},
    volume   = {2},
    number   = {1},
    journal  = {GENDER - Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Geschlecht, Kultur und Gesellschaft},
    }

    @book{Mernissi.2011,
    abstract  = {Does Islam as a religion oppress women? Is Islam against democracy? In this classic study, internationally renowned sociologist Fatema Mernissi argues that women's oppression is not due to Islam as this religion in fact celebrates women's power. Women's oppression, she maintains, is due to the political manipulation of religion by powerseeking, archaic Muslim male elites. Mernissi explains in her book that early Muslim scholars portrayed women as aggressive hunters who forced men, reduced to weak hunted victims, to control women by imposing requirements such as veiling, which confined women to},
    author    = {Mernissi, Fatema},
    year      = {2011},
    title     = {Beyond the Veil: Male-Female Dynamics in Muslim Society},
    url       = {http://gbv.eblib.com/patron/FullRecord.aspx?p=845260},
    address   = {New York},
    publisher = {Saqi},
    isbn      = {978-0-86356-479-6},
    series    = {Saqi Essentials},
}   
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    DIV=9, 
    BCOR=-17.5mm,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    bibliography=totoc, 
    ]{scrartcl}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{ngerman}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
bibencoding=utf8,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
%citestyle=verbose,
bibstyle=authoryear,
url=true,
%autocite=footnote,
sorting=nyt,
language=german,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{publisher:}{}

\providecommand{\apashortdash}{-}

\addbibresource{some.bib}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} % besser zitieren, automatisch an Sprache angepasst dank polyglossia


\begin{document}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\section{Intro}

Lorem ipsum\footcite{Mernissi.2011} bla bla. 

\section{Abschnitt}

\subsection{Teilabschnitt mit wichtigen Wörtern}

\begin{german}[variant=german]

\footcite[cf.][]{Salah.2010} ohne Seitenzahl und auch mit Seitenzahl\footcite[cf.][836]{Mernissi.2011}. Ich kann auch im Fließtext mit Seitenangabe zitieren, nämlich \cite[515]{Ahmed.1992}, aber auch ohne wie \cite{Ayubi.2019}
\vspace{12pt}
\newline
\indent \enquote{Direktes Zitat in der Fußnote mit Seitenangabe.}\footcite[161]{Salah.2010}
\vspace{12pt}
\newline
\lipsum[1]

\end{german}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we find the `islamwissenschaft` bibligoraphy style?

Comment: Note that your example `.bib` file does not include the two entries `Ahmed.1992` and `Ayubi.2019` you cite. As Ivan mentions the example references a style called `islamwissenschaft` that is not available on CTAN. Is that the style you are writing? Does it contain anything more than the code shown so far (i.e. can we assume it is functionally equivalent to `authoryear`)?

Comment: About your desired style: Are citations going to be author-year citations? Do you really need to get rid of the title of an `@article`? That is *extremely* unusual (outside chemistry at least)? (Your style examples seem to refer only to books, so it is not clear to me that this would be needed.)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Bibstyle is authoryear.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the year to the end by selecting an `authortitle`-based `bibstyle`. If you do that and still want to retain an `authoryear`-based citation style, it might still be a good idea to select `sorting=nyt,` to sort by name, year and title, even though the year of publication is much harder to find now.

I base my answer on the `biblatex-ext` versions of the `biblatex` standard styles involved here, because that makes a few things a tad easier.

There are several ways to get rid of the `publisher` here, I chose `\DeclareListInputHandler`, but you could also redefine the relevant bibmacro (`publisher+location+date` [standard `biblatex`] or `pubinstorg+location+date` [`biblatex-ext`]). With `biblatex-ext` the punctuation between `location` and `date` is controlled by `\locdatedelim`.

I did not do anything more for the name format, because it was not mentioned explicitly in the question, because the style suggests two alternatives (and I didn't know which you preferred) and because it all looks a bit inconsistent to me.

For the indentation you can use

```
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2\itemsep}
```

but I think I prefer the `biblatex` standard indentation (and it is not always clear whether the indentation is part of the requirement or not).

I removed all superfluous `biblatex` options. In particular the option `language` rarely does what people think it does. `bibencoding=utf8,` is auto-detected when you use XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX or a modern LaTeX kernel)

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    DIV=9, 
    BCOR=-17.5mm,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    bibliography=totoc, 
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareListInputHandler{publisher}{\def\NewValue{}}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2\itemsep}

\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Salah.2010,
  author   = {Salah, Hoda},
  year     = {2010},
  title    = {Diskurse des islamischen Feminismus},
  pages    = {47--64},
  volume   = {2},
  number   = {1},
  journal  = {GENDER -- Zeitschrift für Geschlecht, Kultur und Gesellschaft},
}
@book{Mernissi.2011,
  author    = {Mernissi, Fatema},
  year      = {2011},
  title     = {Beyond the Veil: Male-Female Dynamics in Muslim Society},
  url       = {http://gbv.eblib.com/patron/FullRecord.aspx?p=845260},
  address   = {New York},
  publisher = {Saqi},
  isbn      = {978-0-86356-479-6},
  series    = {Saqi Essentials},
}   
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
Lorem ipsum\footcite{Mernissi.2011} bla bla. 

\section{Abschnitt}
\subsection{Teilabschnitt mit wichtigen Wörtern}
Lorem\footcite[cf.][]{Salah.2010}
ipsum\footcite[cf.][836]{Mernissi.2011}.
\blockcquote[161]{Salah.2010}{\lipsum[2] Direktes Zitat in der Fußnote mit Seitenangabe.}
\lipsum[2]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MERNISSI, Fatema: Beyond the Veil: Male-Female Dynamics in Muslim Society. Saqi Essentials. New York 2011.]